# WPF, Как сделать различные варианты отображения для окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть окно, с общим набором элементов(в данном случае 4 кнопки: Yes, No, Ok, Cancel) под разные случаи. Как сделать различные "варианты" отображения этого окна, что бы при вызове какого то из вариантов из кода отображались те или иные кнопки?
Как то привязать Visible кнопок к условию, или Enum`у?

```
<Window x:Class="Test.View.ConfirmationMessageBoxView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Com.Controls.MessageBox.Converters"
    Title="asd"
    Width="618"
    MinHeight="180"
    MaxHeight="800"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    SizeToContent="Height"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    Height="245">
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:EnumToVisibilityConverter x:Key="EnumToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <converters:NotificationIconConverter x:Key="NotificationIconConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Width="48"
        Height="48"
        Margin="16,20,16,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Name="mainTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,0">
        Внимание!<LineBreak></LineBreak>
        Тут должен быть текст <LineBreak></LineBreak>
         <TextBox Background="Transparent" Margin="0"
         BorderThickness="0"
         Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" /><LineBreak></LineBreak>
        Нажмите подробнее и выполните рекомендации.
    </TextBlock>
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="319*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="45*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Content="Yes" Width="75" Height="23" Margin="0,0,10,0" Visibility="{Binding YesVisibility, Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter}}"
                    Command="{Binding ReturnYesCommand}" >
            </Button>
            <Button Content="No" Width="75" Height="23" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                    Command="{Binding ReturnYesCommand}" Visibility=" Collapsed">
            </Button>
            <Button Content="OK" Width="75" Height="23" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                    Command="{Binding ReturnYesCommand}" Visibility="{Binding OkVisibility}">
            </Button>
            <Button Content="Cancel" Width="75" Height="23" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
                    Command="{Binding ReturnYesCommand}" Visibility="{Binding CancelVisibility}">
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```
 class NotificationViewModel
{

    private LinkParameters linkParameters;
    private bool _isDontShowCheckBoxVisible;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private NotificationIcon _notificationIcon;

    private ObservableCollection<ButtonModel> _MyData = new ObservableCollection<ButtonModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<ButtonModel> MyData { get { return _MyData; } }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Action<object>> commands;
    private InformationBoxButtons buttons;
    private InformationBoxResult result = InformationBoxResult.None;


    private bool YesVisibility = false;
    private Visibility NoVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    private Visibility OkVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    private Visibility CancelVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;


    private CommandHandler _returnYesCommand;
    private CommandHandler _returnNoCommand;
    private CommandHandler _returnOkCommand;
    private CommandHandler _returnCloseCommand;

    public NotificationViewModel(string content, InformationBoxButtons buttons)
    {
        this.buttons = buttons;
        //SetButtons();

    }

    public ICommand ReturnYesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _returnYesCommand = new CommandHandler(SayYes,true);
            return _returnYesCommand;
        }
    }

    private void SayYes(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Called Yes method(s)");
    }

    public bool IsDontShowCheckBoxVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _isDontShowCheckBoxVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _isDontShowCheckBoxVisible = value;
            onPropertyChanged("IsDontShowCheckBoxVisible");
        }
    }

    public NotificationIcon NotificationIcon
    {
        get
        {
            return _notificationIcon;
        }
        set
        {
            _notificationIcon = value;
            onPropertyChanged("NotificationIcon");
        }
    }




    private void SetButtons()
    {
        if (buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OK ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKCancel ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKCancelUser1 ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKCancelDetails ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKClipboardDetails ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKDetails)
        {
            OkVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        // Yes
        if (buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNo ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoCancel ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoUser1 ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoDetails)
        {
            YesVisibility = true;
        }
        // No
        if (buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNo ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoCancel ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoUser1 ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoDetails)
        {
            NoVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        // Cancel
        if (buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKCancel ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKCancelUser1 ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.RetryCancel ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.YesNoCancel ||
            buttons == InformationBoxButtons.OKCancelDetails)
        {
            CancelVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }



    //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void onPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Я сомневаюсь, что диалоговым окнам нужна VM, считаю что всевозможные подтверждения - это область ответственности GUI, чисто вьюшная задача. Поэтому можно хоть в codebehind скрыть ненужные кнопки. А вообще, ответ на ваш вопрос - конвертер, конечно же

Comment: Я бы написал ответ как сделать все кнопки с одной командой, а все кнопки положить в один контрол, и менять в зависимости от `enum`, но это муторно. Обойдусь комментарием.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пусть у нас имеется такое перечисление:

```
[Flags]
public enum DialogOptions
{
    Yes = 1,
    No = 2,
    OK = 4,
    Cancel = 8,

    YesNo = Yes | No,
    YesNoCancel = Yes | No | Cancel,
    OKOnly = OK,
    OKCancel = OK | Cancel
}
```

Для удобства использования в разметке я написал такое простое расширение:

```
class DialogOptionExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public DialogOptions Value { get; set; }
    public DialogOptionExtension() { }
    public DialogOptionExtension(DialogOptions value) => Value = value;
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => Value;
}
```

и конвертер:

```
class DialogOptionToVisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var avaible = (DialogOptions)value;
        var current = (DialogOptions)parameter;
        return avaible.HasFlag(current) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
}
```

В классе окна я делаю конструктор приватным и добавляю недостающие свойства. Для показа диалогового окна я написал статический метод:

```
public partial class DialogWindow : Window
{
    public DialogOptions Options { get; }
    public DelegateCommand PickCommand { get; }
    public DialogOptions Result { get; private set; }
    bool isPicked = false;

    DialogWindow(DialogOptions options)
    {
        Options = options;
        PickCommand = new DelegateCommand(o => { Result = (DialogOptions)o; isPicked = true; Close(); });
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) => e.Cancel = !isPicked;

    public static DialogOptions Show(string title, string caption, DialogOptions options)
    {
        var window = new DialogWindow(options) { Title = title, Caption = { Text = caption } };
        window.ShowDialog();
        return window.Result;
    }
}
```

Разметка окна:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.DialogWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance c:DialogWindow}"
        mc:Ignorable="d" Width="300" SizeToContent="Height"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Name="Caption" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Rows="1"
                     Margin="0,5,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <UniformGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2.5,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding PickCommand}"/>
                </Style>
            </UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Button Content="Yes" CommandParameter="{c:DialogOption Yes}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Options, Converter={c:DialogOptionToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={c:DialogOption Yes}}"/>

            <Button Content="No" CommandParameter="{c:DialogOption No}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Options, Converter={c:DialogOptionToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={c:DialogOption No}}"/>

            <Button Content="OK" CommandParameter="{c:DialogOption OK}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Options, Converter={c:DialogOptionToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={c:DialogOption OK}}"/>

            <Button Content="Cancel" CommandParameter="{c:DialogOption Cancel}"
                    Visibility="{Binding Options, Converter={c:DialogOptionToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={c:DialogOption Cancel}}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Показывать диалог можно, например, так:

```
var result = DialogWindow.Show("Выход", "Вы уверены?", DialogOptions.YesNo);
```

Вам остается лишь реализовать выбор и отображение иконки диалога.

Еще я бы добавил установку Default и Cancel кнопок. Ну и действие по крестику (сейчас по крестику окно не закрывается вообще).

Еще один из шагов сокращения разметки - добавить кнопке AttachedProperty, которое будет хранить `DialogOptions`, тогда установку `CommandParameter` и `Visibility` тоже можно будет вынести в стиль